# how will the checkbox's in the struts2 tag checkboxlist should appear in column wise not in row wise?

Tags: struts2

how can i arrange the checkbox's in the struts2 tag checkboxlist in the form of table to display it in the column wise , so that i can hide the borders n view it in column wise

list="communityList" value="defaultSelect" />

Answer (score 0):

I do this with an custom template, just extract the struts2-core.jar and copy the checkboxlist.ftl into your WebApp/template folder. after this you can modify it like you want.

in the struts2 checkbox tag you must now specify the templateDir and the checkboxes was displayed like estimated.

Comment: Please can you help me answer this question. I don't seem to come up with a solution. The url is [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353130/how-to-display-pass-values-to-struts-2-checkboxlist-tag). Thanks